# Is this Ruby class really badly designed?

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm quite new to OOP and I'm concerned that this class that I've written is really poorly designed. It seems to disobey several principles of OOP:

1. It doesn't contain its own data, but relies on a yaml file for
   values.
2. Its methods need to be called in a particular order
3. It has a lot of instance variables and methods

It does work, however. It's robust, but I'll need to modify the source code to add new getter methods every time I add page elements

It's a model of an html document used in an automated test suite. I keep thinking that some of the methods could be put in subclasses, but I'm concerned that I'd have too many classes then.

What do you think?

```
class BrandFlightsPage < FlightSearchPage

  attr_reader :route, :date, :itinerary_type, :no_of_pax,
              :no_results_error_container, :submit_button_element

  def initialize(browser, page, brand)
    super(browser, page)

    #Get reference to config file
    config_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'site_config.yml')

    #Store hash of config values in local variable
    config = YAML.load_file config_file

    @brand = brand        #brand is specified by the customer in the features file

    #Define instance variables from the hash keys
    config.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}",v)
    end

  end

  def visit
    @browser.goto(@start_url)
  end

  def set_origin(origin)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute] => @route[:origin]).set origin
  end

  def set_destination(destination)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute] => @route[:destination]).set destination
  end

  def set_departure_date(outbound)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute]  => @date[:outgoing_date]).set outbound
  end

  def set_journey_type(type)
    if type == "return"
      self.radio(@route[:attribute]  => @itinerary_type[:single]).set
    else
      self.radio(@route[:attribute]  => @itinerary_type[:return]).set
    end
  end

  def set_return_date(inbound)
    self.text_field(@route[:attribute]  => @date[:incoming_date]).set inbound
  end

  def set_number_of_adults(adults)
     self.select_list(@route[:attribute]  => @no_of_pax[:adults]).select adults
  end

  def set_no_of_children(children)
    self.select_list(@route[:attribute]  => @no_of_pax[:children]).select children
  end

  def set_no_of_seniors(seniors)
    self.select_list(@route[:attribute]  => @no_of_adults[:seniors]).select seniors
  end

  def no_flights_found_message
    @browser.div(@no_results_error_container[:attribute] => @no_results_error_container[:error_element]).text
    raise UserErrorNotDisplayed, "Expected user error message not displayed" unless divFlightResultErrTitle.exists?
  end

  def submit_search
    self.link(@submit_button_element[:attribute] => @submit_button_element[:button_element]).click
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this class is designed as a Facade, then it's not (too) bad design. It provides a coherent unified way to perform related operations that rely on a variety of un-related behavior holders.

It appears to be poor separation of concerns, in that this class essentially coupling all the various implementation details, which might turn out to be somewhat tricky to maintain.

Finally, the fact methods need to be called in a specific order may hint at the fact you're trying to model a state machine - in which case it probably should be broken down to several classes (one per "state"). I don't think there's a "too many methods" or "too many classes" point you'd reach, the fact is you need the features provided by each class to be coherent and making sense. Where to draw the line is up to you and your specific implementation's domain requirements.

Comment: Thanks Romain. What you're saying is essentially what concerned me - I was considering subclassing from BrandFlightsPage - things like BrandFlightsPageAddPorts and BrandFlightsPageAddDates. This would add robustness and allow extension without modification. It would require changes in the code that consumes the objects, but as this hasn't been forked or released, all that means is a little extra work upfront. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: That could work. `BrandFlightsPage` would then centralize the common logic between all specialized versions. But you should try to ensure the "order" constraints of calls cannot be violated, if that is feasible.

Comment: I think that's feasible - this is support code for cucumber automated tests, so the features file and step code will enforce order. Thanks for your help.